# Social Slider not working. CSS Transition

Tags: css, transition

Im new here have seen a lot of this site and videos around the internet and now i have a problem with my CSS fort i would say hello and see if there is any one out there that can help me out.
Im righting a website and have a sliding bar on my nav.
but the text witch is hiden then shows on hover will not stay on the same line intel it is open full, As im making this site on a local host cant show you sorry but here is the code…

```
<p data-height="257" data-theme-id="9309" data-slug-hash="icrwC" data-default-tab="result" data-user="jandrew" class='codepen'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/jandrew/pen/icrwC/'>Social Slider</a> by jerome Andrew (<a href='http://codepen.io/jandrew'>@jandrew</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="//codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

[would like it to work](http://codepen.io/jandrew/pen/icrwC/)

Thanks to any one that can help :)
My site as it is at the moo.. lots of work needs doing
[my site](http://boswebdesign.co.uk/new/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in the css in ".socialSlider li"

It will prevent the line from wrapping.